# Change Date format to Chinese

Tags: javascript, date

I have a JSP page where a date is populated in a test box from a Java Method according to the language of the user.We are currently allowing the user to access the site in Chinese and English

The date when the user is using Chinese language is populated as below - 
10-10月-2012.

But when user selects a different date from date picker js (which I could not change) the date is coming to normal format 10-OCT-2012.

Is it possible to change the date format to Chinese again using Javascript after the user selects it?

Comment: Which date picker and is it the picker that has a language setting?

Comment: We are using Date Format 1.2.3 by Steve Levithan [link]http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format